# My gulpfile doesn't compile

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I passed the last few days searching how to resolve my issue but didn't find.
My gulpfile does not compile my css however I do.
My gulpfile was originally for sass files and worked perfectly. I changed it into scss for this project and it juste broke.
Here is my gulpfile:

```
/* Modules
------------------------------------- */
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
// Tools
watch         = require('gulp-watch'),
rename        = require("gulp-rename"),

// Styles
sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

// Prevent watch from crashing on errors
plumber       = require('gulp-plumber'),


gulp_src      = gulp.src;

gulp.src = function() {
 return gulp_src.apply(gulp, arguments)
.pipe(plumber(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
  this.emit('end');
    })
  );
};


/* Paths
------------------------------------- */
var paths = {
 sass: './assets/scss/',
 css: './assets/css/',
 templates: './assets/scss/templates/'
}


// Autoprefixer Task
gulp.task('autoprefix', function () {

gulp.src(paths.css + 'application.css')

.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))
});



// Sass Task
gulp.task('sass',  function () {

gulp.src(paths.scss + 'application.scss')
.pipe(sass({indentedSyntax: true}))

//Autoprefixer
.pipe(autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['> 2%'],
    cascade: false
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css))

});


 /* METHOD ------------------------------------- */

// Watch Task
gulp.task('watch', function () {
gulp.watch(paths.scss+'**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

//
// DEFAULT
gulp.task('default' , ['watch']);
```

And here is my folders structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbH7u.png)

Also here is how gulp react on the terminal:
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqmmD.png)

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second line of the paths object to:

```
var paths = {
  scss: './assets/scss/',
  css: './assets/css/',
  templates: './assets/scss/templates/'
}
```

since your 'sass' task uses "paths.**scss**"  not "paths.**sass**"